# Apache Zeppelin | Notebook Access Control Issue | Non Owners can add themself as Owner

Tags: bigdata, shiro, apache-zeppelin

Apache Zeppelin | Notebook Access Control Not Working

Test Steps to see the issue:
1. Logged in to zeppelin as user1 and create a note book called **MyNote1**

2.Update the notebook access control as follows
Owners : user1
Readers : user1,user2
Writers : user1

3.Log out and login as user2

Issue:

As per above setting user2 should only have ReadOnly access to **MyNote1**,However user2 is able click the little icon 
called **"Note Permissions"** and add himself(user2) as a Owner for the notebook.Which allows him to get the ReadWrite permission for the notebook.

I see this as an issue here because user2 is not authorised to change anything as per the notebook permission setup.

SetUp Info:
Zeppelin with Shiro Authentication Enabled(No LDAP or Active Directory)

```
 ++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Shiro.ini Settings:
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++
    [users]
    admin = password1, admin
user1 = password2, role1
user2 = password3, role2

[roles]
admin = *
role1 = NoteCreators
role2 = NoteReaders

[urls]
/api/version = anon
/** = authc


 ++++++++++++++++++++++++
zeppelin-site.xml Settings:
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Anonymous allowed has been set to false

Comment: I think this is a bug. I tested this in zeppelin 0.7.3 from a custom build and it performs this way. Zeppelin is far from finished as a product

Comment: @MichailN got it .. thanks for your prompt response